# I am looking for a way to stop html injection

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, security, sanitization

If I send the request like `<img src = "1"/>`, it seems it does not work in this
case. I am using owasp policy factory sanitizer.

Can you describe the issue and how can I fix it ?

```
PolicyFactory policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
    .allowElements("a")
    .allowUrlProtocols("https")
    .allowAttributes("href").onElements("a")
    .requireRelNofollowOnLinks()
    .allowAttributes("src").onElements("img")
    .build();
```

I am expecting to
return an empty string.

Comment: Well you explicitely stated you want to allow `src` attributes on `<img>`s..?

Comment: Even if i remove it i still does not sanitize it

Comment: Can you please share a [mcve] containing all the code necessary to reproduce it? How did you sanitize it?

Comment: .disallowAttributes("src").matching(Pattern.compile("^(?!.*<img\\s+src).*$")).onElements("img")
I think i solved it with  disallowing attributes that contains img src.

Comment: Don't be so certain - there may still be ways to bypass it.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: I said there may be ways to bypass it, not that I have an example. Nevertheless, I could imagine it being possible using something like `< img src="1">` (note the space) - If you want to sanitize something, you need to make sure that there is absolutely no possibility that anything can come through. Using regexes seems like a bad idea in that regard.